# Remove multiple redundant nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I had an XML file which I wanted to visualize in Neo4j (as a graph with interconnected nodes). The XML file had the following hierarchy:

```
<Organism>
 <Enzyme>
  <Motif>
```

I was successful in creating the entire graph. When I finished I realized that a lot of times different `organisms` had a common `enzyme` or 2 different `enzymes` had common `motifs`. Now there is a lot of redundancy in my graph with similar `enzymes` or `motifs` occuring multiple times. Is there an easier way to remove **all except 1 of the node** (either an `enzyme or motif`) and then connect it to different nodes? Or will i have to start from scratch?

My CREATE statements looked like this:

```
CREATE (jejunistrain81176:Organism { name: "Campylobacter jejuni strain 81-176" })
CREATE (jejunistrain81176_e1:Enzyme { name: "CjeFIII" })
CREATE (jejunistrain81176_m1:Motif { name: "GCAAGG" })
CREATE UNIQUE (jejunistrain81176)-[:HAS_ENZYME]->(jejunistrain81176_e1)
CREATE UNIQUE (jejunistrain81176_e1)-[:HAS_MOTIF]->(jejunistrain81176_m1)
```

I tried replacing all the `CREATE` with `MERGE` but it gives me the following error :

```
Invalid input '(': expected whitespace, comment, '=', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, ON, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 21, column 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing create and create unique with merge should actually work.

You'd have to create an index or constraint for your :Label(name) pairs.

I think you're faster reimporting the data, if you want to delete and reconnect nodes you need to know which relationships you're looking at.

Something like:

```
MATCH (e:Enzyme)
WITH e.name as name, count(*) as cnt, collect(e) as enzymes
where cnt > 1
WITH enzymes[0] as first, enzymes[1..] as remove
UNWIND remove as enzyme
MATCH (enzyme)<-[rel:HAS_ENZYME]-(organism)
MERGE (first)<-[newRel:HAS_ENZYME]-(organism) ON CREATE SET newRel = rel
DELETE rel
WITH distinct first, enzyme
MATCH (enzyme)-[rel:HAS_MOTIV]->(motiv)
MERGE (first)-[newRel:HAS_MOTIV]->(motiv) ON CREATE SET newRel = rel
DELETE rel
DELETE enzyme;
```

Comment: I have about 3 days experience with Neo4j so I am way too skeptical for trying out new commands. I actually typed in every entry into the database as neo4j xml imports are very complex. Retyping it will be a bummer. Reimporting sounds good but how is the question

Comment: Use a text editor to keep your statements and organize them there, then you can use copy & paste and also share them via github-gists or dropbox.

Comment: I have been doing that. But I dont think it helps in removing the redundancy